# Magento2 downloadable product customoptions section position changing

Tags: magento2, product, downloadable

can anyone help me to how to move customoptions section to below the product descriptions section.

Please find the screenshot below:

[image]

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, create your own `default.xml` in `view/frontend/layout` with the content below:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <move element="product.info.options.wrapper" destination="product.info.options.container"/>
        <referenceContainer name="product.info.main">
            <container name="product.info.options.container" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="product.info.options.container" after="product.info.price"/>
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

Don't forget remove var/gerenation. Here is my result. Hope it help you!
[image]

**EDIT:**
I have make a mistake. The removing `product.info.options.wrapper` make the option select out of form. So the product can validate for add to cart. Please undo the previous change and do the following way:

1.Add new file name `catalog_product_view_type_downloadable.xml` to override the core layout. Then add the below code:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <move element="product.info" destination="product.info.main" after="alert.urls"/>
    </body>
</page>
```

The effect not much beautiful so you have to add your own `CSS` file to restyle it.
This is my result.
[image]

Now, the option will take right price.

Comment: Hi, its working but for dropdown custom options price is not updating

Comment: Could you show me the options?

Comment: Hi find the screenshot:https://prnt.sc/hamznl

Comment: Seem like you are using firefox. F12 and check Network to see what happen when change the select box.

Comment: it seems like:https://prnt.sc/han52j

Comment: No, check the Network tab, not Inspector. Pick Inspector tab and change select box. After that take a screenshoot. Also take a screenshoot in Console tab.

Comment: network tab is like this:https://prnt.sc/han9pd

Comment: iam not getting any console errors while changing the dropdown

Comment: Check the Network tab which network is POST method or get error!

Comment: it is like this:https://prnt.sc/hanbvt

Comment: find the screenshot

Comment: Is there any network get error in that list?

Comment: no network get error there iam not seeing that kind of errors

Comment: Try go through and add to cart. Check the price of product if it change within option in checkout

Comment: the product is not going to addtocart section: getting like
Please specify product's required option(s).

Comment: we have selected the dropdown required option

Comment: Maybe we have moved just the select box, not the Product Option section. I'll check and update solution.

Comment: You're welcome!

Comment: Have you got the solution @shivashankarm?

Comment: No @Nero Phung Still  iam waiting for proper answer.

Comment: OK mate. I'm too busy for whole 2 weeks. Let me help you!

Comment: @shivashankarm I have edited my solution mate!

Comment: Thanks for the answer mate, i will confirm once its worked.